# How to use whitespace without spamming <br/>

Tags: html

I have the following code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <meta charset="UTF-8">
        <title>Unified Bank</title>
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
        <script src="script.js"></script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <h1>Lorem Ipsum</h1>
        <div id="Lorem">
            <button>Ipsum</button>
            <button>Lorem</button>
        </div>
        <br/>
        <a href="forgot.html">Forgot Password?</a>
    </body>
</html>
```

I would like to have a lot of space between the `<header>` and the `<button>`, however this will require a lot of `<br/>` tags, as well as making the code a little messy. Is there a different way to do this?

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/margin

Comment: Probably [`padding`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/padding) would help (or `margin` as it has been mentioned).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the CSS [`margin`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/margin) property to add space around an element.

```
<h1 style="margin-bottom: 100px;">Lorem Ipsum</h1>
```

```css
.push-bottom {
   margin-bottom: 70px;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <meta charset="UTF-8">
        <title>Unified Bank</title>
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
        <script src="script.js"></script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <h1 class="push-bottom">Lorem Ipsum</h1>
        <div id="Lorem">
            <button>Ipsum</button>
            <button>Lorem</button>
        </div>
        <br/>
        <a href="forgot.html">Forgot Password?</a>
    </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1):

You can do this with the [`margin`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/margin) attribute in CSS. You can do this by using either `margin-bottom` or `margin-top` by assigning them to your individual elements.

1. **Using `margin-bottom`**. In order to do this, you just have to assign the `margin-bottom` attribute to your desired element.

```css
#Lorem {
  margin-bottom: 40px;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <title>Unified Bank</title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
  <script src="script.js"></script>
</head>

<body>
  <h1>Lorem Ipsum</h1>
  <div id="Lorem">
    <button>Ipsum</button>
    <button>Lorem</button>
  </div>
  <br/>
  <a href="forgot.html">Forgot Password?</a>
</body>

</html>
```

2. **Using `margin-top`**. This is the same as the first approach but in your particular case, with a little difference, since `a` tag is an inline element, you should specify it's [`display`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/display) also in order to margin attribute take effect.

```css
a {
  display: block;
  margin-top: 40px;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <title>Unified Bank</title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
  <script src="script.js"></script>
</head>

<body>
  <h1>Lorem Ipsum</h1>
  <div id="Lorem">
    <button>Ipsum</button>
    <button>Lorem</button>
  </div>
  <br/>
  <a href="forgot.html">Forgot Password?</a>
</body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

As bad practice to use

```
<pre>


... any white space you need
</pre>
```

As good practice - `margin/padding` or `flexbox` at your service.